# CakePHP Fatal error: Call to a member function check() on a non-object?

Tags: php, session, cakephp

Hey everyone I am getting this error

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function check() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\job_portal_cakephp\app\Controller\Component\SeekerSessionComponent.php
>   on line 4"

Component Code(SeekerSessionComponent.php)

```
<?php
class SeekerSessionComponent extends Component{
    function session_check(){
        if(!$this->Session->check("id")){
            die;
            $this->redirect(array("controller"=>"Pages","action"=>"login"));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Controller Code(PagesController.php)

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');


class PagesController extends AppController {
public $name = 'Pages';


public $helpers = array('Html', 'Session');


public $uses = array("Job","Page","Seeker","Skill");

public $components = array("Sanitize","SeekerSession");

public function index(){
    $this->SeekerSession->session_check();
    $this->layout = "first_layout";
    $jobs = $this->Job->query();
    $this->set(compact("jobs"));
}
}
```

I have Pages controller which has index function which uses SeekerSessionComponent to check if session with variable "id" exists or not.

Comment: check your class that this function is define or not?

Comment: `App::uses(Component, Controller);` is missed in your component class code:- https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component  and function must be `public`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on link:-https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component

You forgot to add `App::uses(Component, Controller);` in your component class code.So it should be like below:-

```
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');//missed

class SeekerSessionComponent extends Component {
   public $components = array('Session');// missed
    public function session_check(){
        if($this->Session->check("id")){ // if id exist
            return true; //return true
        }
    }
}
```

Note:-

component function must be `public`.

***Also***

`die;$this->redirect(array("controller"=>"Pages","action"=>"login"));` it doesn't seems correct code, you need to `return` something not stopping execution or redirecting to any page .

Answer (score 0):

Check by printing $this->Session in 4th line of your code mentioned above. This is returning a null value means it does not return any object and then your code tries to call check() function on null.

```
 <?php
    class SeekerSessionComponent extends Component{
        function session_check(){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($this->Session);
            die;
            /*if(!$this->Session->check("id")){
                die;
                $this->redirect(array("controller"=>"Pages","action"=>"login"));
            }*/
        }
    }
    ?>
```